# Cannot play mp3 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have

```
function playAudio( spext ) {
    if( spext == "mp3" ){
        document.getElementById("bpShow").innerHTML = "<audio><source src='/group/16/624.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'></audio>";
    }
    else if( spext == "wav" ){
        document.getElementById("bpShow").innerHTML = "<audio><source src='/group/16/623.wav' type='audio/wav'></audio>";
    }
}
```

Mp3 and wav are in one folder. I can play the wav file without any problems, but not the mp3.

When I run playAudio() console returns:

> GET http://localhost/group/16/624.mp3 [HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> 0ms]

What is wrong?

Console output:
[image: When I run mp3 file]

Comment: Did you read the error message? Looks like the URL is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP status code of [301 Moved Permanently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) means that the file has been moved, but if it did not actually exist, you would get a [404 Not Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404). I believe that your localhost server is trying to redirect to a file that does not actually exist. Make sure that the resources are avaialble by navigating directly to their location in the browser.

Furthemore, you should use a lookup to determine which type of track to inject into the HTML.

```js
const tracks = [{
  name: 'Track 01',
  mp3: '/group/16/624.mp3',
  wav: '/group/16/623.wav',
}]

const audioMimeType = Object.freeze({
  'mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
  'wav': 'audio/wav',
});

function playAudio(index, ext) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= tracks.length) throw new Error('Index out of bounds!');
  const src = tracks[index][ext], type = audioMimeType[ext];
  if (src) {
    document.getElementById("bpShow").innerHTML = `
      <audio>
        <source src="${src}" type="${type}">
      </audio>
    `;
  }
}

playAudio(0, 'wav'); // Play 'Track 01' as a WAV
```

```html
<div id="bpShow"></div>
```